# How to skip job in gitlab-ci.yml base on different runner?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cross-platform

I am using the gitlab as my CI/CD system. And I need setup my own runner.
I have two runner both 'windows' with 'powershell' and 'macos' with 'shell'. I want either of them can run my build job. The 'macos' is a laptop so it not always online. So I write two version of build jobs, and hope just execute one of them for different runner.

When I use the runner tags, both of the job will execute. And the build will execute twice. If my 'macos' is offline, the `build-mac` will stuck.

```
build-win:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - windows
  script: powershell command...

build-mac:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - macos
  script: shell command...
```

So I think I need 'skip' the job but not select a runner. So I am trying to use `only` or `rules` to skip the job. I find the linkage: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21860
But as the issues said, the `CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH` can not use in `only`, `except` and `rules`.

```
build-win:
  stage: build
  script: powershell command...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH =~ /^windows.*/

build-mac:
  stage: build
  script: shell command...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_RUNNER_EXECUTABLE_ARCH =~ /^(darwin|linux).*/
```

I think both of the solution is not suitable. Is there any better way to do this?
Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not seeing any options in [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.htmlhttps://) for anything like runner online status.

If you want to base a run rule by runner status, you will probably have to leverage a personal token (or maybe a project token) to hit the runners api for status. You could do something like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - check-runner
  - run

image: python

check runner:
  stage: check-runner
  script:
    - curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$READ_RUNNERS_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/runners?tag_list=unreliable"
    - |
      echo RUNNER_STATUS=$(\
      curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$READ_RUNNERS_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/runners?tag_list=macos" \
      | python -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[0]['status'])" \
      ) >> .env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: .env

use tagged runner:
  stage: run
  script:
    - echo $RUNNER_STATUS
  dependencies:
    - check runner
  rules:
    - if: '$RUNNER_STATUS == "online"'
  tags:
    - macos

user other runner:
  stage: run
  script:
    - echo "used runner"
  dependencies:
    - check runner
  rules:
    - if: '$RUNNER_STATUS != "online"'
  tags:
    - windows
```

Comment: Thank you. Learn a lot from the script. Indeed I have to check runner status in an individual job. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $CI_RUNNER_TAGS or $CI_RUNNER_ID [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

Example:

```yaml
rules:
- if: $CI_RUNNER_TAGS == windows
```

Or:

```yaml
rules:
- if: $CI_RUNNER_TAGS == macos
```

Comment: Thanks, the CI_RUNNER_TAGS is a comma-separated list of the runner tags. So should I use the regex with =~? If both the windows and macos runner is all online, the build will execute twice but I want only one. Is there a way to deal with this?